# SEO Best Practices for page title, meta tag and page content

Tags: seo

I have a question regarding search engine optimisation.  I did some research on my niche and I found the following keywords to be most relevant to my niche (this is just sample text, not the real keywords):

learn english
learn english online
learn english free

**Meta Tag**
If I were to add the keywords to the meta tag, what will the keywords have to look like?  Must they be the exact phrases above, individual words or a combination of both?

**Page Title**
How would I use these keywords in a page title, what is best practices?

**Page Content**
If I write an introductory paragraph, do I need to include all 3 phrases exactly as they are?

I am trying to follow best practices on SEO.  I would appreciate as much comments as possible.

Thanks

Comment: not really programming related...

Comment: Pity there's no "belongs on doctype.com" choice when we vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keywords are almost always formatted as phrases separated by commas.  In your case, something like "learn english, learn english online, learn english free".  Though i'm not sure if search engines will coalesce the phrases to the point where just "learn english free online" would accomplish the same thing.

The best way to use the keywords, either as the title or as the content, is as a naturally flowing part of the text.  Don't just stick a bunch of keywords into the title, and likewise don't just have a page full of "learn english" every other word.  (1) It looks cheesy, and (2) there's a certain, undisclosed threshold for how many keywords can be in a given piece of text before search engines (especially google) consider it "keyword spamming".  That's something you definitely don't want -- keyword spammers can get lower rankings or get dropped from the listings entirely if the way you're doing it is considered too shady.